# Prints in console, but not in on page?

Tags: html, next.js, tailwind-css

Can anyone spot the issue here?

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CoinTable(props){
    props.data.map(row=> {
        console.log(row.first_name)
    })

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Subscription</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    props.data.map(row => {
                        <tr>
                            <td>{row.first_name} {row.last_name}</td>                     
                            <td>{row.phone}</td> 
                            <td>{row.email}</td>                                           
                        </tr>
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

For some reason the code appears on console but not on the screen. I am also printing from a JSON file if that helps.

Comment: In the second map, what does it print to the console if you put console.log(row)?

Comment: Could you show the code where you assign value to `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return the DOM in `map`.

```
props.data.map(row => {
    return (
       <tr>
         <td>{row.first_name} {row.last_name}</td>                     
         <td>{row.phone}</td> 
         <td>{row.email}</td>                                           
      </tr>
    )
})
```

Or precisely:

```
props.data.map(row => (
       <tr>
         <td>{row.first_name} {row.last_name}</td>                     
         <td>{row.phone}</td> 
         <td>{row.email}</td>                                           
      </tr>
))
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I'll try these at work on Monday. I'm a little new to NextJS and whatnot so yeah.